# System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException in UnityEngine.dll

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, unity-game-engine

I am importing unity3D project for windows phone 8. and adding few lines of code which interact the c# code to the event changing handler of Object(SphereScript) in unity3D.

```
var sphereScript = UnityEngine.Object.FindObjectOfType<SphereScript>();
sphereScript.SphereStateChanged += sphereScript_SphereStateChanged;
sphereScript_SphereStateChanged(sphereScript.IsSphereMoving);
```

The project compiled fine with no errors but when it runs on phone it gives an error on line

```
UnityEngine.Object.FindObjectOfType<SphereScript>();
```

An exception of type **'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException'** occurred in UnityEngine.DLL but was not handled in user code. i don't know why this error occurs. but first time when i started the project it asked me to locate the file name **UnityEngineObject.cs**. Where can i find this file or how can i solve the problem. Thanks.

Url for complete code  http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/wp8-unity-interaction.html

Exception details:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException was unhandled by user code 
HResult=-2147467259 
Message=External component has thrown an exception. 
Source=UnityEngine 
ErrorCode=-2147467259 

StackTrace: 
at UnityEngine.Internal.$Calli.Invoke38(Int32 arg0, IntPtr method) 
at UnityEngine.Object.FindObjectsOfType(Type type) 
at UnityEngine.Object.FindObjectOfType(Type type) 
at UnityEngine.Object.FindObjectOfType[T]() 
at UnityXamlInteractionExample.MainPage.Unity_Loaded() 

InnerException:
```

Comment: Can you add a stack trace of the thrown exception?

Answer (score 0):

in Unity 5x i had equal the problem.
So try this:

In script SphereScript.cs:

re-write this:

```
public event Action<bool> SphereStateChanged;
```

to this:

```
public static event  Action<bool> SphereStateChanged = delegate { };
```

next, in Visual Studio after build project un-comment these parts of code:

```
UnityApp.SetLoadedCallback(() => { Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Unity_Loaded); });

private void Unity_Loaded() { }
```

now insert into *private void Unity_Loaded()* this:

```
ShareScript.SphereStateChanged += SphereStateChanged;
```

and finally add this:

```
void SphereStateChanged(bool currentSpehreState)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        SphereStateTextBlock.Text = currentSpehreState ? "Spehre is moving" : "Sphere is stopped";
    });
}
```

Good luck, bye :)